# How to get Joda-Time LocalTime same with that stored in SQL Server using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jodatime

I stored "06:00:00" in a SQL Server database as a `time(0)` type. Our time zone is "Australia/Sydney". How can I convert the time to "06:00" in Java code using Joda-Time?

I have tried the following:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime")
@Column private LocalTime openTime;
```

No matter how I format the time, it always is "16:00".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We would love to answer your question but it would help if we had more details of your code. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if you can edit your question to provide some clarity.

Comment: Fixed by add this     @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "Australia/Sydney")})            don't know why, I guess this is a bug of usertype

Comment: Great! maybe you can answer your own question to be of use to subsequent users?

Comment: Yes, the current solution is  @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "jvm")})

Answer (score 0):

(From the comment by @JohnLuan)

The correct solution is the following:

```
@Type(
    type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalTime",
    parameters = { @Parameter(name = "databaseZone", value = "jvm") }
 )
```